# About suspend subscription in paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am working on PayPal and want to know when we suspend subscription on PayPal, does it makes service available to user?

Is there anything similar in paypal like cancel at period end in stripe?

I want to know what exactly suspend do in paypal

Comment: What are you talking about?  What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Suspending a subscription puts it on hold. It can be reactivated later, or not. No payments will occur while a subscription is suspended, this is straightforward.

PayPal is not in the business of "making services available to a user", that is something you do -- or don't do. The best way to track whether a subscription is valid is to subscribe to the webhook event PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED. Every time your webhook listener URL receives this event for a subscription, update its valid through date in your records. When that date comes, by the end of it if you don't receive a new PAYMENET.SALE.COMPLETED event, the subscription has lapsed.

For reconciliation purposes it can be useful to add a `custom_id` parameter and value when creating the subscription. This value will be returned in all webhook events so you know who/what the subscription is for.